# Proving algebraic equations given one is true

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider a problem, where an algebraic equation $A$ is given, and we are asked to show that this means another algebraic equation $B$ is true. That is $A⇒B$. Is it sufficient to start with $B$ and show how this is equivalent to $A$, or must we start with $A$ and work towards $B$?

For example, given $ad=cb$, show $(a^2+c^2)(b^2+d^2)=(ab+cd)^2$. Is it sufficient to start with the latter and show that $ad=cb$ is true?

Comment: No.  $A\implies B$ does not imply that $B\implies A$.  $"a=b"\implies a^2=b^2$ but $a^2=b^2\nRightarrow a=b$.

Comment: Side question:  anyone know a better way of formatting "not implies"?  using "\not \implies" yields $\not \implies$ which is terrible.  I used \nRightarrow which kind of works but which is really not great.

Comment: You want $ad-bc = 0$  to show that $$(a^2+c^2)(b^2+d^2)-(ab+cd)^2  \; =  \; \;  a^2 d^2 -2adbc + b^2 c^2$$  is also zero. This one now factors

Comment: @lulu try {\kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies}

Comment: @CyclotomicField  Perfect!  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, if you start with B and show it is *equivalent* to A, that implies that A ⇒ B (as well as that B ⇒ A). But if you do this, you need to make sure that each step is *equivalent* to the next, not merely implies it.